# can anyone translate any of this seal script on an old bronze please

Tags: translation, character-identification, traditional-characters

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Ancient Chinese Small seal script translation.

Comment: the leftest lower 5th & 4th characters are “司用”

Comment: The characters are real (and not small seal script - they're [Western Zhou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [bronze inscriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)), but I don't think this says anything coherent. There's way too many 王、用、寶、且（祖）、月 scattered all over the place. You'd typically only find at most 1 or 2 occurrences of them in a real inscription.

Comment: and, several 子、乙、周、孫；hard to make any semantically guess  any more clear pictures of the texts, and, of the whole artefact?

Comment: Added more pictures

Comment: besides, i highly recommend you contact christie's, or sotheby's; their hong kong offices have experts in chinese related artefacts 

Comment: interesting  the format, most likely, would be classified as “簋” (圈足無蓋無耳), a “vessel used to hold offerings of food” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gui_(vessel) about the texts, i’ll try again, please wait

Comment: I am going to try to do a rubbing of the characters.